# How to get iTunes volume control widget?

Tags: objective-c, slider, itunes, volume

Anyone know of a way to get a volume control widget similar to iTunes?

[image]

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. I haven't started yet. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how close you'll get but the tutorial below shows how to apply custom themes via images to a UISlider.  I haven't tried it yet but I was looking at it the other day.

http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=250

I found it when browsing the site below which is also a good resource when trying to find controls

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls

Hope that helps